# Can't install DefinitelyTyped Typescript definitions. Getting "Permission denied (publickey)." via npm

Tags: git, npm, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I'm currently trying to install the type definition for bleno from the DefinitelyTyped repo. The command I'm using is

```
npm install --save @types/bleno
```

But it seems I'm not allowed to clone the Repo.

```
npm WARN package.json BluetoothServer@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json BluetoothServer@0.0.1 No README data
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/bleno Cloning into bare 
repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-types-bleno-
71caf4ab'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/bleno Permission denied 
(publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/bleno fatal: Could not read 
from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/bleno 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/bleno Please make sure you have 
the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/bleno and the repository 
exists.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install types/bleno
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'types/bleno'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.41-v7+     
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save" 
"@types/bleno"
npm ERR! cwd /home/nils/BluetoothServer
npm ERR! node -v v4.8.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! path types/bleno
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nils/BluetoothServer/npm-debug.log 
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Of course I tried to use sudo and I added the ssh key to github and I'm able to connect to github via

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

but my problem persists. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After spending the morning trying to solve the problem, of course shortly after asking I found the soultion. I upgraded npm to version 3.10.10 and it worked, no problem.